# Logs containing json strings in fluent-bit

Tags: fluent-bit

I have the following fluent-bit configuration.
However, unescaped json strings are not inserted into elasticsearch.
Is this due to the configuration?

```
output-elasticsearch.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           *
        Host            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
        Port            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
        Logstash_Format Off
        Replace_Dots    On
        Retry_Limit     False
        Suppress_Type_Name On
        Index           myapp
        HTTP_User       ${ELASTICSEARCH_USER}
        HTTP_Passwd     ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}

parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name   json
        Format json
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z

    [PARSER]
        Name        docker
        Format      json
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
        Time_Keep   On

    [PARSER]
        Name        syslog
        Format      regex
        Regex       ^\<(?<pri>[0-9]+)\>(?<time>[^ ]* {1,2}[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<ident>[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.\-]*)(?:\[(?<pid>[0-9]+)\])?(?:[^\:]*\:)? *(?<message>.*)$
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %b %d %H:%M:%S
```

```
{"cursor":"/go/src/github.com/myapp/main.go#L45","function":"main.main","level":"INFO","message":"{"connection_key":""}","time":"2024-02-14T14:28:10Z"}
```